# How to display a css grid in different order?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a page with a little complex CSS Grid.

See the picture for expected result.

See the snippet for my bad code ;-)

The difficulty is when I want to position  inside , I cannot (I tried many many ways...)

How to do this only with CSS ? Thanks for your help.

### ---------------

[image: Expected result]

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-gap: 20px;

    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, minmax(100px, auto));
    grid-template-columns: 100px repeat(5, 1fr);
    background: #fff;
    }

.box {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    }


#logo {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
    }
#menu {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 2 / span 5;
    }


#main {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1 / span 4;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    }


#aside_B {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    }


#aside_A {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 5 / span 2;
    }


#footer {
    grid-row: 4;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <header id="logo">LOGO</header>

    <nav id="menu" class="box">MENU</nav>

    <main id="main">
        <article id="article" class="box">Article</article>

        <aside id="aside_B" class="box">
B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B
        </aside>
    </main>

    <aside id="aside_A" class="box">
        A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A
    </aside>

    <footer id="footer" class="box">Footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your `DOM` to achieve desire result. Check Snippet.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  padding: 20px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, minmax(100px, auto));
  grid-template-columns: 100px repeat(5, 1fr);
  background: #fff;
}

.box {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

#logo {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

#menu {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2 / span 5;
}

#main {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

#aside_B {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

#aside_A {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 5 / span 2;
}

#footer {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<header id="logo">LOGO</header>

<nav id="menu" class="box">MENU</nav>

<main id="main">
  <article id="article" class="box">Article</article>
</main>

<aside id="aside_A" class="box">
  A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A
</aside>
<aside id="aside_B" class="box">
  B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B
</aside>

<footer id="footer" class="box">Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I need to keep <aside id="aside_B" class="box"> inside <main>. I need to find a solution only with CSS. Do you think it's possible with css grid only ?

Comment: If you put the aside_B inside your main then you have to bring aside_A inside then and only then it will be possible, let me know if both aside can be inside main

Comment: Unfortunately, I need <aside id="aside_A" class="box"> outside of the <main>. This is my problem...

Comment: In that case its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Did u consider using grid-areas for this purpose?I think grid-areas will be more appropriate in your case.

Also you can checkout codepen for css grid areas examples.